# Wordpress - load jQuery in head on specific page Template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a page template that needs jQuery loaded in the header instead of the footer.

The Theme (Divi Theme) loads jQuery in the footer by default. This causes some errors, when jQuery is loaded twice.

Is there any way I can modify `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` to exclude jQuery for this template?

Thanks.

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/styles/cam-forms.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>        
  </head>
  <body>       
    <?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('form') );  ?>    
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't import it as a CDN?

Comment: No specific reason. But good call, I might change that. Thanks. This doesn't sovle my problem, though, right? :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the following place:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/styles/cam-forms.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/cam-forms/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <?php wp_head(): ?>  
  </head>
  <body>       
    <?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('form') );  ?>    
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, in you file functions.php add this..

```
function theme_scripts(){
  wp_register_script('fileName', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/file.js', array( ), '1.0.0');
  wp_enqueue_script('fileName');
}
add_action('init', 'theme_scripts');
```

Also I always suggest you to work with the minified files for CSS and JS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not sure how this helps me. I'm aware how to add scripts/css this way. But my question is how to REMOVE/EXCLUDE a script (jquery) from being included in the footer. 

Just to be clear:
I removed the wp_head since it also loads a ton of other scripts that aren't necessary on these page templates.

Answer (score 0):

add below function in function.php for add js and css file in header and remove file in footer

```
<?php
remove_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
function mycustomscript_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ca-forms-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cam-forms/styles/cam-forms.min.css', array('ca-forms-min'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/cam-forms/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/cam-forms/js/jquery-migrate.min.js', array( 'jquery-migrate' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mycustomscript_enqueue' );
?>
```